# How to work with Mezzanine

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

**processor_for.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from mezzanine.pages.page_processors import processor_for
from .models import Book

class BookForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()

@processor_for(Author)
def author_form(request, page):
    form = BookForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form =BookForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Form processing goes here.
            redirect = request.path + "?submitted=true"
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect)
    return {"form": form}
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from time import time
class Book(models.Model):
   book_name= models.CharField(max_length=200, unique = True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.book_name
```

**views.py**

```
def create_book (request):
    if request.POST:
        form = BookForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/all/')
    else:
        form = BookForm()
    args= {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = form
    return render_to_response('create_Book.html', args)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^/xyz/$', create_book))
```

**create_Book.html**

```
<form action="/xyz/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_ul}}
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="create"/>
</form>
```

This is what i am doing but still i am unable to access form. Where i am doing wrong. will be grateful to you. Please mark that what's wrong in code?

Comment: unable to access form  ??? can u explain more ??  i can't see url pattern for  createuser into your urls.py  code.

Comment: please explain you are not able to see only template or form  ?? what is issue exactly  ??

Comment: issue is: i am using mezzanine. i want to use proccessor_for .py file and mezzanine.pages.views.page to make form visible on page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Two Syntax Problems:***

1) Always define your processor name in " " like `@processor_for("Author")`

2) urls for page processors like :

```
 url("^xyz/$", "mezzanine.pages.views.page", {"slug": "Author"},  name="Author"),
```

Answer (score 0):

as per you code and your explanation in question .please see your code in urls.py

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^xyz/$', create_book))       # you should write like ^xyz/$
```

Please follow [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/)